# Why can't this user connect to domain share?

Tags: active-directory, backup, permissions

Part of my reorganizing credentials in the domain, I have created several users that will be used solely for services (backup, LDAP, etc)

The idea is that systems that need specific usage will use a user/service user, that will give them what they need.

However, I am having trouble setting the correct needed data.

For this example, I have a NAS (Ready NAS 1100 by Netgear), that runs it's own backup jobs. The job reads from a domain share: \domain\qa and copies all data to another location.
When using the domain\administrator everything works. When I input the domain\srv.backup user I get an error connecting to the folder.

[image]

The srv.backup is part of the 'Domain Admins' group, which is a member of 'Administrators'

- I thought there might be propagation issues, but even when the srv.backup user was a direct member of 'Administrators' the error still occurred.
- I have 2 DC's (W2K8R2 replicas) - I thought that could also cause a problem, AFAIKT it's not the issue.

Sharing permissions are open to everyone

[image]

The Security on the folder is as follow

[image]

This is the test window from the NAS dashboard

[image]

I doubled check that the 'srv.domain' is part of the 'Domain Admins' group

[image]

As well as tried with a simple 1-9 password.

What else do I need to check? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you get when you try the following command?

```
net use * \\domain\qa /user:domain\srv.backup
```

Try the Account allowed logon locations

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I get: System Error 2240. the user is not allowed to login from this workstation. - that showed me the problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/257025/change-list-of-allowed-logon-computers-from-batch-file  Solved. thanks